# Thymeleaf Login and Logout Visibility Problem

Tags: html, authentication, thymeleaf, logout

I am developing a website and using springboot and thymeleaf for this process. The problem is I cannot seem to get the logout button to display when I am logged in. I have the Login displayed when I am not logged out though. I have two types of users-User and Admin. The login and logout should work for both types of users. Below is my code for the login and logout in the html. I have also attached what I have in the controller. Thanks
menu.html and mycontroller.java

```
<a th:if="${userRole == 'null'}">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark m-2">Logout</button>
</a>
<a th:unless="${userRole == 'null'}">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark m-2">Login</button>
</a>




private void setUpNavBar(Model model) {
    String presentUserRole;
    if (userSession.getUser() == null) presentUserRole = "noUser";
    else presentUserRole = userSession.getUser().getRole();
    model.addAttribute("userRole",presentUserRole);
    System.out.println("setting up navigation bar:" + presentUserRole);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that userRole never becomes 'null'. If you follow your setUpNavBar, userRole is either 'noUser' or the role (userSession.getUser().getRole()).

So replace 'null' with 'noUser'.

Comment: I am going to try that now. Thanks @Robson